# Is it possible to trigger a command after a specific one?

Tags: fish

Whenever I run `systemctl start <something>` or `systemctl restart <something>`, I would like to also run `systemctl status <something>`

**Is there a way to trigger a command after a specific one has been issued?**

I was considering the possibility to write an alis which would run both commands in a row but I could not understand how to keep autocompletion for the first command. Today when I type

```
systemctl start apa<tab>
```

I am autocompleted to

```
systemctl start apache2.service
```

By using a `function` I loose (or not?) the capacity to autocomplete and keep this autocomplete result to run a new command with it as an argument

Comment: Was the answer I provided helpful? If so, perhaps mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [Fish documentation for `function`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function), the `--wraps` / `-w` flag can be used to indicate that the specified command's completions should be inherited by the new function. For example:

```
function sstart --wraps systemctl -d "Start service and show its status"
    systemctl start $argv
    systemctl status $argv
end
```